# PHP equivalent of Java Servlet

Tags: java, php, jsp, servlets

I am trying to understand what's the correspondent of servlets and applets in PHP but I don't have much experience in JAVA.

I want to know *what is the equivalent of Java Servlets and JSP in PHP ?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java the Servlet delivers the web page to the client. In PHP there are multiple web server which delivers the same functionality:

- Apache2
- NginX
- lighttpd

The PHP script is similar to JSP. It was designed to be used as template.

However overtime PHP was used more and more also not only for templates. In the last year there are appearing new approaches where PHP is used to write an entire web server. E.g.

- appserver.io
- reactphp

Answer (score 0):

I think the equivalent of Java Servlets and JSP is PHP.

Taken from Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet:

"The servlet is a Java programming language class used to extend the capabilities of a server. Although servlets can respond to any types of requests, they are commonly used to extend the applications hosted by web servers, so they can be thought of as Java applets that run on servers instead of in web browsers.[1] These kinds of servlets are the Java counterpart to other dynamic Web content technologies such as PHP and ASP.NET."